# Upload build artefact in GitLab CI to S3 doesn't work

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab-ci

On GitLab CI I have a build where I generate some static files and deploy these files to s3 using dpl.

My command is: 

`- npm run build-static && dpl --provider=s3 --access-key-id=$ACCESS_KEY_ID --secret_access_key=$SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --bucket=staging.teletext.io --region=eu-west-1 --acl=public_read`

The build works fine, the console output is as I expect. This generates a build/public folder on the runner, but when dpl uploads everything to s3, everything is there except the build/public folder itself.

Why isn't the new folder uploaded?

EDIT: the problem is in DPL. I created a Grunt script at uploads the files instead of using DPL and that works fine. I don't know why DPL doesn't see the generated files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in DPL itself. There is a flag `--skip-cleanup` which should be set, according to documentation:

`Dpl will deploy by default from the latest commit. Use the --skip_cleanup flag to deploy from the current file state. Note that many providers deploy by git and could ignore this option.`